# trying to achieve an automatic open -> close in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

so i'm doing a project for school with tkinter
what i'm currently trying to do is display an image that is a 450x450px .gif

what it needs to do is 
open > 20sec delay > close

here is the current code

```
    photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './Images/img1.gif')
    root.geometry("450x450")
    root.update()
    canvas.create_image(225,225, image=photo)
    root.mainloop()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSCce.png is the current result

Comment: i mean to close the image, but `canvas.destroy()` won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the return value of the `create_image` (item id), then use that value when you delete the image using [`canvas.delete`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.html#Tkinter.Canvas.delete-method).

```
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = './Images/img1.gif')
root.geometry("450x450")
root.update()
img = canvas.create_image(225,225, image=photo)
root.after(20000, lambda: canvas.delete(img)) # 20,000 milli seconds = 20 seconds
root.mainloop()
```

Using [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method), you can do some stuff after specified time.

Comment: Thanks! this solves half the problem, i just need to find out how to display the whole image and not that bit of it.

Comment: @Photonium, I don't understand the last sentence.

Comment: check the image link in the OP, you'll see what i mean

Comment: @Photonium, Do you mean this? http://pastebin.com/DxSrYRQA or http://pastebin.com/1hgZ5uZS

Comment: actually, since this solves the stated problem, im going to just create a new question since i'm trying to solve what i didn't ask for.